# sqlite combine 2 queries from different tables to make one

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I recently took to using sql again, the last time I used it was in microsoft access 2000 so please bear with me if I'm behind the times a little.

I have 2 pointless virtual currencies on my discord server for my players to play pointless games with. Both of these currencies' transactions are currently stored in individual tables.

I wish to sum up all the transactions for each player to give them a single current amount for each currency. Individually I can do this:

```sql
SELECT
 tblPlayers.PlayerID AS PlayerID,
 tblPlayers.Name AS Name,
 SUM(tblGorillaTears.Amount) 
FROM 
 tblPlayers 
INNER JOIN 
 tblGorillaTears
ON 
 tblPlayers.PlayerID = tblGorillaTears.PlayerID 
GROUP BY 
 tblPlayers.PlayerID;
```

and

```sql
SELECT
 tblPlayers.PlayerID AS PlayerID,
 tblPlayers.Name AS Name,
 SUM(tblKebabs.Amount) 
FROM 
 tblPlayers 
INNER JOIN 
 tblKebabs 
ON 
 tblPlayers.PlayerID = tblKebabs.PlayerID 
GROUP BY 
 tblPlayers.PlayerID;
```

What i need is a table that outputs the user name the id and the total for each currency on one row, but when i do this:

```sql
SELECT
 tblPlayers.PlayerID AS PlayerID,
 tblPlayers.Name AS Name,
 SUM(tblGorillaTears.Amount) AS GT,
 0 as Kebabs
FROM 
 tblPlayers 
INNER JOIN 
 tblGorillaTears
ON 
 tblPlayers.PlayerID = tblGorillaTears.PlayerID 
GROUP BY 
 tblPlayers.PlayerID
UNION 
SELECT
 tblPlayers.PlayerID AS PlayerID,
 tblPlayers.Name AS Name,
 0 as GP,
 SUM(tblKebabs.Amount) 
FROM 
 tblPlayers 
INNER JOIN 
 tblKebabs 
ON 
 tblPlayers.PlayerID = tblKebabs.PlayerID 
GROUP BY 
 tblPlayers.PlayerID;
```

the results end in a row for each player for each currency. How can i make it so both currencies appear in the same row?

Previously in MSAccess i was able to create two queries and then make a query of those two queries as if they were a table, but I cannot figure out how to do that in this instance. Thanks <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNION` will add new rows for sure, you can try like following query.

```
SELECT TP.playerid                        AS PlayerID, 
       TP.NAME                            AS NAME, 
       (SELECT Sum(TG.amount) 
        FROM   tblgorillatears TG 
        WHERE  TG.playerid = TP.playerid) AS GT, 
       (SELECT Sum(TG.amount) 
        FROM   tblkebabs TG 
        WHERE  TG.playerid = TP.playerid) AS Kebabs 
FROM   tblplayers TP
```

Comment: Excellent @PSK, thank you so very much. now that first query you posted gives the output table in the correct format, but the values output are horrifically innacurate to the point of sheer comedy. the sub queries method however is both formatted correctly and accurate data. Thank you for making my morning better <3

Comment: @Ramalamafizzfaj, thanks for letting me know, i will remove the left join part, It's' hard to guess the issue without without data :)